# c# xml multiple elements

Tags: c#, xml

These are my 2 attempts at retrieving these multiple elements, the 1st only selects the first box & first text element

the 2nd retrieves all, but they are not separate variables--

```
var xmlDoc = document.Root.Elements("Page")
                          .Select(element => new
                          {
                             Box = (string)element.Element("Box"),
                             Text = (string)element.Element("Text"),
                          }).ToList();


var xmlDoc = document.Root.Descendants("Page")
                          .Elements()
                          .Select(x => x.Value)
                          .ToList();
```

xml sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<PrintJob>
<Page>
<Box>0000,0000,0190,0135</Box>
<Box>0050,0100,0190,0135</Box>
<Text>0000,0000,"ABCdef123456"</Text>
<Text>0000,0000,"ABCdef123456"</Text>
<Text>0000,0050,"ABCdef123456"</Text>
<Text>0000,0050,"ABCdef123456"</Text>
</Page>
</PrintJob>
```

loop to retrieve elements:

```
foreach (var x in xmlDoc)
{
   //result += "box: " + x.Box + "\n";
   //result += "text: " + x.Text + "\n";
   result += "x: " + x + "\n";
}
```

how to I get results like this:

```
box: 0000,0000,0190,0135
box: 0050,0100,0190,0135
text: 0000,0000,"ABCdef123456"
text: 0000,0000,"ABCdef123456"
text: 0000,0050,"ABCdef123456"
text: 0000,0050,"ABCdef123456"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
var page = document.Element("PrintJob")
                   .Element("Page");

var boxes = page.Elements("Box")
                .Select(x => (string)x)
                .ToList();

var texts = page.Elements("Text")
                .Select(x => (string)x)
                .ToList();

foreach (var box in boxes)
    Console.WriteLine("Box: " + box);
foreach (var text in texts)
    Console.WriteLine("Text: " + text);
```

*Output:*

```
Box: 0000,0000,0190,0135
Box: 0050,0100,0190,0135
Text: 0000,0000,"ABCdef123456"
Text: 0000,0000,"ABCdef123456"
Text: 0000,0050,"ABCdef123456"
Text: 0000,0050,"ABCdef123456"
```

---

```
var items = document.Element("PrintJob")
                    .Element("Page")
                    .Elements()
                    .Select(x => x.Name.LocalName + ": " + (string)x)
                    .ToList();

foreach (var item in items)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

*Output:*

```
Box: 0000,0000,0190,0135
Box: 0050,0100,0190,0135
Text: 0000,0000,"ABCdef123456"
Text: 0000,0000,"ABCdef123456"
Text: 0000,0050,"ABCdef123456"
Text: 0000,0050,"ABCdef123456"
```

---

```
var items = document.Element("PrintJob")
                    .Element("Page")
                    .Elements()
                    .Select(x => new
                                 {
                                     Box  = (x.Name.LocalName == "Box")
                                          ? (string)x
                                          : null,
                                     Text = (x.Name.LocalName == "Text")
                                          ? (string)x
                                          : null
                                 })
                    .ToList();

foreach (var item in items)
    Console.WriteLine("Box: " + item.Box + " Text: " + item.Text);
```

*Output:*

```
Box: 0000,0000,0190,0135 Text:
Box: 0050,0100,0190,0135 Text:
Box: Text: 0000,0000,"ABCdef123456"
Box: Text: 0000,0000,"ABCdef123456"
Box: Text: 0000,0050,"ABCdef123456"
Box: Text: 0000,0050,"ABCdef123456"
```

Comment: looks good, can it be done with just one list, like a variation of my 1st example? -- maybe that's not the way to go, but trying to understand this--

Comment: from your 2nd answer, how can you do: foreach(var item in items) Console.WriteLine("Box: " + item.Box + "Text: " + item.Text )

Comment: @Scott: What should be the output for this?

Comment: the output will look the same, just need to pick out the separate box/text elements ultimately, and I like the 2nd example--

Comment: @Scott: Added another example. You should probably use custom classes instead of an anonymous type, for instance, `abstract class PageItem { } class Box : PageItem { } class Text : PageItem { }`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var xmlDoc = document.Root.Descendants("Page")
                          .Elements();
foreach(var x in xmlDoc)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x.Name + ": " + x.Value);
}
```